# For loop empty statement issue

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double Qd, Qe, Hd, He, Hplus, B, Leffd, Leffe, Ln, np, bp, Ka, Kp, Cd, Ce, Qhesapd, Qhesape, farkd, farke;

            Qd = 60.30;
            Qe = 120;
            Hd = 0.0001;
            He = 0.0001;
            Hplus = 1;
            B = 8.2;
            np = 1;
            bp = 1.2;
            Ka = 0.1;
            Kp = 0.01;
            Ln = B - np * bp;
            Leffd = Ln - (Ka + Kp * np) * 2 * Hd;
            Leffe = Ln - (Ka + Kp * np) * 2 * He;
            Cd = 0.3849 * (1 + (4) / (14));
            Ce = 0.3849 * (1 + (4 * Hplus) / (9 + 5 * Hplus));
            Qhesapd = Cd * Leffd * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Hd, 3) * 19.62);
            Qhesape = Ce * Leffe * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(He, 3) * 19.62);
            farkd = Qhesapd - Qd;
            farke = Qhesape - Qe;

        for (Hd = 0.0001; farkd < 0.0001; Hd+=0.0001)
            {
                Cd = 0.49487;
                Leffd = Ln - (Ka + Kp * np) * 2 * Hd;
                Qhesapd = Cd * Leffd * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Hd, 3) * 19.62);
                farkd = Qhesapd - Qd;
            }
            label1.Text = Math.Round(Cd,5).ToString();
            label2.Text = Math.Round(Leffd, 4).ToString();
            label3.Text = Math.Round(Hd, 4).ToString();

        //Where things get weird//

        for (He = 0.0001; farke < 0.0001; He += 0.0001);
            {
                Hplus = He / Hd;
                Ce = 0.3849 * (1 + (4 * Hplus) / (9 + 5 * Hplus));
                Leffe = Ln - (Ka + Kp * np) * 2 * He;
                Qhesape = Ce * Leffe * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(He, 3) * 19.62);
                farke = Qhesape - Qe;
            }
            label4.Text = Math.Round(Ce, 5).ToString();
            label5.Text = Math.Round(Leffe, 4).ToString();
            label6.Text = Math.Round(He, 4).ToString();


        }
    }
```

There is a comment line between 2 for loops. If I don't add second for loop, the code works perfectly. In first loop I obtain a 'Hd' value and I'm using this value in second loop, is it wrong? By the way, there is warning about second loop in error list which says "Possible mistaken empty statements".

Comment: Look closely at `for (He = 0.0001; farke < 0.0001; He += 0.0001);` <=== SEMICOLON AT THE END!

Comment: `for (He = 0.0001; farke < 0.0001; He += 0.0001);` remove `;` at the end of for loop.

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+naming+conventions&*

Comment: oh, working to fix this for an hour but i didn't realize that semicolon.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the line! This is a typical mistake you should be careful of in the future... It makes the `for` loop *do nothing*

```
for (He = 0.0001; farke < 0.0001; He += 0.0001);
```